# cesium calculate heading and pitch from 2 cartesian3 points

Tags: cesiumjs

I'm trying to calculate heading and pitch using two cartesian3 points in Cesium as follwing:

```
getHeading(pointA,pointB){
    const transform=Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(pointA);
    const vector2=Cesium.Cartesian3.subtract(pointA,pointB,new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    const vector=Cesium.Matrix4.multiplyByPoint(fixedTransform,vector2,new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    const direction=Cesium.Cartesian3.normalize(vector,new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    const heading=Math.atan2(direction.y,direction.x)-Cesium.Math.PI_OVER_TWO;
    return Cesium.Math.toDegrees(Cesium.Math.TWO_PI-Cesium.Math.zeroToTwoPi(heading));
}
```

but it dont work,Can anyone give me some advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**solution:**

```
getHeading(pointA:Cesium.Cartesian3,pointB:Cesium.Cartesian3){
    const transform=Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(pointA);
    const positionvector=Cesium.Cartesian3.subtract(pointB,pointA,new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    const vector=Cesium.Matrix4.multiplyByPointAsVector(Cesium.Matrix4.inverse(transform,new Cesium.Matrix4()),positionvector,new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    const direction=Cesium.Cartesian3.normalize(vector,new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    //heading
    const heading=Math.atan2(direction.y,direction.x)-Cesium.Math.PI_OVER_TWO;
    //pitch
    const pitch=Cesium.Math.PI_OVER_TWO-Cesium.Math.acosClamped(direction.z);
    return Cesium.Math.toDegrees(Cesium.Math.TWO_PI-Cesium.Math.zeroToTwoPi(heading));
}
```